# How to enable --leak-check=yes for valgrind in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, qt-creator, valgrind

**System Info:** Ubuntu 16.04, Qt Creator 4.2.0, valgrind 3.12.0

When using valgrind from the console to output detailed leak analysis I do it like that:

`valgrind --leak-check=yes ./my_application --an_argument`

Since I want to use Qt Creator's nice output formatting and filtering of the reported issues I tried to use valgrind within the editor but I cannot configure any arguments (such as --leak-check) for valgrind itself. The dialog looks like this:

[image: valgrind configuration within Qt Creator]

Can I do this somewhere in a config file or in hidden dialog options?

**Edit:** I accepted the answer that explicitly mentions the --leak-check option but other answers mentioning a wrapper script from inside Qt Creator is a very nice way to go. Unfortunately there is still a difference in the outputs within Qt Creator compared to valgrind from the console so I guess that there are suppression files used inside Qt Creator... but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the 'Check for leaks on finish' option value to 'Full':

[image]

This will spawn the `'--leak-check=full'` valgrind option which is equivalent to `'--leak-check=yes'`.

Comment: Thanks but the results differ. I intentionally placed different leaking code lines in different source files which are correctly detected using valgrind via the console. I already played with the settings in the dialog but they seem to have another impact. How do you know that this option should reflect the "--leak-check=yes" functionality? And what if I wanted to customize valgrind's behavior in another fashion?

Comment: I've examined the Qt Creator [source code](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/43936b1e8619ec8cc25d7699e53b638d8f0627b1/src/plugins/valgrind/memchecktool.cpp#L222).

Comment: You've done your homework! :-) There is only small diference between "yes" and "full" so I will investigate that further. Thanks for the time being!

Comment: Just to clarify: to open the valgrind settings, you need to click "Tools" in the top menu, then "Parameters", and then "Analyzer" in the list on the left.

Answer (score 4):

In the worst case you can create a wrapper for the `valgrind` binary with the desired options. You would create an executable file `valgrind` somewhere:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/valgrind --leak-check "$@"
```

Then in the QtCreator settings put the new file's filepath in the `Valgrind executable` field.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've used that approach for some special configurations in the past. I keep the question open for now but this is definitely a solution that works:-)